# Android Recyclerview item visibility

Tags: android, row, visibility, android-recyclerview

I want to make is that: When i was scroll the recycleview if i see row then i want to show "Visible: .. " text on log window. But i show only "Not visible .." text.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("Row", holder.text.isShown() ? ("Visible: " + position) : ("Not visible: " + position))
    }

    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView text

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
```

I use this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: your ques is unclear.Please add some more details or code

Comment: Add this log after setting visiblity of view.

Comment: refresh my code. where can i add? maybe onBindViewHolder doesnt finish the draw or cant control draw?

Comment: I have same issue as you